# Putty Wyse60 emulation

Tags: putty, terminal, aix

I have AIX (v.7) box and using TinyTerm app. 
However Id prefer to use Putty instead.
Problem is I do not have there proper key mapping - I miss there Wyse60 emulation.

Is there any way to configure putty to work with AIX ?

Comment: As far as I know, the only terminal type that putty correctly emates is `putty`. Aix doesn't know this terminal-type by default, but it can be installed with `tic` utility (execute command `infocmp putty >putty.ti` on some Linux machine to get the input-file of `tic`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define "work". ssh from PuTTY to AIX should *connect* with both at their defaults. Getting the key sequences sent, the server terminfo, applications, and character encoding to all agree, is what makes a good text experience.

---

Try [each of the Terminal > Keyboard modes](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-keyboard), in particular VT400 and VT100+.

The server also needs to expect correct type so terminfo is correct. Try changing ‘Terminal-type string’ if `xterm` is not to your liking, such as to good ol' `vt220`.

It is unclear exactly which of your applications are expecting which sequences. Use the `cat` trick from the PuTTY FAQ to make both working and not working keys printable.

> ### [A.7.13 One or more function keys don't do what I expected in a  server-side application.](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/AppendixA.html#faq-keyboard)
>
> If you've already tried all the relevant
>   options in the PuTTY Keyboard panel, you may need to mail the PuTTY
>   maintainers and ask.
>
> PuTTY responds to function key presses by sending a sequence of
>   control characters to the server. If a function key isn't doing what
>   you expect, it's likely that the character sequence your application
>   is expecting to receive is not the same as the one PuTTY is sending.
>   Therefore what we really need to know is what sequence the application
>   is expecting.
>
> The simplest way to investigate this is to find some other terminal
>   environment, in which that function key does work; and then
>   investigate what sequence the function key is sending in that
>   situation. One reasonably easy way to do this on a Unix system is to
>   type the command `cat`, and then press the function key. This is likely
>   to produce output of the form `^[[11~`. You can also do this in PuTTY,
>   to find out what sequence the function key is producing in that.